# Order by for a Day on whereMonth for Eloquent Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel

Error to order by for a day on month.

> this my query

```
$birthday = \App\Admin\Clients::whereMonth('birthday', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->month)->orderBy('birthday', 'asc')->get();
```

ordering for year, my good is a ordering for day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
$birthday = \App\Admin\Clients::whereMonth('birthday', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->month)
            ->orderByRaw('day(birthday) asc')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm not knew use `orderByRaw`